# How can I use one DB model with multiple server?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, database-design, koa2

I have 2 Node.js server and they both have to use the same DB model(mongoDB), and the reason for them to use the same DB is because DB has to be synced every time there's a change. after a long thought I came up with these ideas, but they don't seem like a best solution.

1. Make a `models` folder out of projects, import the folder from the both project. and It'd be like

[image]

2. Make a `models` folder in `project1` folder, import it from `project2` folder.

[image]

Comment: you can run no of apps in different port in single nodejs application

Comment: For multiple server go with DB Replica and multiple machine you can use sharding in mongoDB

Comment: Your models can be as lib or service with HTTP API